# How to Create Additional Table in Activity within a Tab

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout, android-tabactivity

I would like to add an additional independent row in my existing activity that already consist of a table layout within a tab. The new table should be below the existing table layout. However, the independent table is not showing. What is the best way to do that?

XML:

```
<LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/tab3"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:orientation="vertical"
         android:paddingTop="60dp" >

        <ScrollView 

            android:id="@+id/scrollView_CustomerProductList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical|start">

         <TableLayout
             android:id="@+id/Tab3_Table"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
             android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

             <TableRow
                 android:id="@+id/table_Row1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:gravity="center">
                                <ListView
                                    android:id="@+id/list_image"
                                    android:layout_width="15dip"
                                    android:layout_height="30dip"
                                    android:src = "@drawable/banana_chair"/>
                                <ListView
                                    android:id="@+id/list_image2"
                                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                                    android:layout_height="80dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/circular_chair"/>
                                <ListView
                                    android:id="@+id/list_image3"
                                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                                    android:layout_height="80dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/purplechair"/>
             </TableRow>

              <TableRow
                 android:id="@+id/table_Row2"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:gravity="center">                 
              </TableRow>

              <TableRow
                 android:id="@+id/table_Row3"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:orientation="vertical"
                 android:gravity="center">
             </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>



            </ScrollView>
            <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TableLayout
                            android:id="@+id/Cost_table"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/costTable_Row1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                </TableRow> 
                                <TableRow
                                    android:id="@+id/costTable_Row1"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                </TableRow> 
                     </TableLayout>
             </LinearLayout>


         </LinearLayout>
```

code that is calling the independent row:

```
TableLayout cost_table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.Cost_table);

// Create Table Header
TableRow tl_cost = new TableRow(this);
 tl_cost.setId(10);
tl_cost.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
tl_cost.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

// Create Table Columns

TextView cost_tab3 = new TextView(this);
cost_tab3.setId(50);
cost_tab3.setText("Total Cost 总价：");
cost_tab3.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
cost_tab3.setPadding(50, 20, 50, 20);    

tl_cost.addView(cost_tab3);// add the column to the table row here

TextView cost_totalamt = new TextView(this);
cost_totalamt.setId(50);
cost_totalamt.setText("total sum:");
cost_totalamt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
cost_totalamt.setPadding(300, 20, 300, 20);  

tl_cost.addView(cost_totalamt);// add the column to the table row here

cost_table.addView(tl_cost, new TableLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input follwing additional code within XML after :

```
<ListView 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="186dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingTop="20px"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Total Cost:">
    </TextView>
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/Cost_table"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20px"
        android:orientation="vertical">
             <TableRow 
                android:id="@+id/costTable_Row1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

             </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```